# Is there an equivalent to `line-mode` and `char-mode` (ansi-term) for multi-term?

Tags: emacs

Any time I try to move around in the buffer (besides moving up and down lines with `C-p` and `C-n`), my cursor is brought back to the command line so I cannot select and copy arbitrary text in the multi-term buffer. I can use my mouse to move to and highlight text, and all goes well from there, but is there a set of key bindings that will allow me to set the mark in other parts of the buffer? I looked in multi-term.el` but was not able to find anything that addressed this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try 'term-line-mode' and 'term-char-mode'

Comment: artscan provides a nice implementation of this here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14485858/multi-term-understanding-keyboard-bindings)