# multi-term: Understanding keyboard bindings

Tags: emacs, elisp

I am a bit confused by the difference between these two lists in [multi-term](http://www.emacswiki.org/MultiTerm) (by the way where is the official repository hosted?)

- `term-bind-key-alist`
- `term-unbind-key-list`

In my head, there should be two things:

- The keystrokes that we want Emacs to capture itself and to interpret in a specific way  (by binding them to commands)
- The strokes that Emacs sends directly to the shell ("as is").

How exactly do `term-unbind-key-list` and `term-bind-key-alist` define these lists and bindings?

Also, does multi-term support **line mode** and **character mode**? If so, how does the mode in which we are alter the way keystrokes and these lists are interpreted?

Answer (score 5):

I saw recipe `multi-term.rcp` for `el-get`, it is downloaded from emacswiki.

`term-bind-key-alist` is for functions like `term-send-up` or `term-previous-input`, whose keybinds are set in "emacs style" instead of "term style".

`term-unbind-key-list` is an analog for setup `'nil` (see [ansi-term in character mode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14491568/1937596)). By default almost all keys in `term-raw-map` are binded to function `term-send-raw` and `'nil` just unbinds them.

`term-bind-key-alist` and `term-unbind-key-list` are used over of `term-raw-map` (**character mode**) and `term-mode-map`(**line mode**) in multi-term.el isn't used at all.

I don't use multi-term, I setup `term-mode-map` and `term-raw-map` directly. For example for switching between modes:

```
(define-key term-mode-map (kbd "C-j") 'term-char-mode)
(define-key term-raw-map (kbd "C-j") 'term-line-mode)
```